# I need to update all Contact Fields dynamically , I am trying throught Schema.SObjectType but getting some Error

Tags: apex, sobject, describesobject, sobjectfield

I need to update all contact records from one record to another record which has 333 fields. It takes time to update this. I thought of updating the sobject field dynamically, but I'm getting "Variable does not exist: fieldvalue" while saving the class.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> m = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Contact existingContact;
List<Schema.SObjectField> fieldsList = new List<Schema.SObjectField>();
Schema.SObjectType s = m.get('Contact');
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = s.getDescribe();
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fields = r.fields.getMap();
for(Contact con : ConList)
{
    for(Schema.SObjectField fieldItems : fields.values()) {
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfield = fieldItems.getDescribe();
        if (dfield.isCreateable() && !dfield.isCalculated()) {
            
            if(con.Id != existingContact.Id)
            {
                
                existingContact.fieldItems = String.isNotBlank(con.fieldItems ) ? con.fieldItems : existingContact.fieldItems ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can it resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
existingContact.fieldvalue= String.isNotBlank(con.fieldvalue) ? con.fieldvalue : existingContact.fieldvalue;
```

with:

```
String f = dfield.getName();
if (String.isNotBlank(con.get(f))) {
    existingContact.put(f, con.get(f));
}
```

or better:

```
SObjectField f = fieldItems;
if (String.isNotBlank(con.get(f))) {
    existingContact.put(f, con.get(f));
}
```

because the `SObjectField` can be used directly as Apex has map-like syntax for dynamic access of SObject fields. See the [SObject Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) documentation.

(JavaScript does offer the syntax you used.)

I also removed the assignment of the `existingContact` value to itself as that seems pointless.

Note that doing this dynamically will likely be slower at runtime than hard coding the field values. But it does have the advantage of getting the set of fields right in the first place and automatically adapting when fields are added. If the fields are unlikely to change in the future, and performance is really important, you could run similar code to this in the Developer Console and output the field API names and hard code those in this logic.

Comment: do you mean existingContact.put(dfield.getName(),con.get(dfield.getName()) ) ?

Comment: still getting error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getName() from the type Schema.SObjectType","Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void isNotBlank(Object) from the type String" ,"Expression cannot be assigned",

Comment: You are right @PranayJaiswal - will change.

Comment: @KeithC i was just testing the above code on ChatGpt and it found the bug..

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Never heard of that - is it good?

Comment: @KeithC very very good.. Its taking world by storm.. almost half of the SE question could be answered by AI.

Comment: @KeithC  existingContact is contact variable, not map

Comment: @Vinithavino any concrete SOBject type like `Contact` is a subclass of the `SObject` type and so has the map-like methods available in the link I provided.

Comment: @KeithC I have tried this , but Contact is not getting updated properly , all the contact fields getting empty expect last name